# Wordpress Plugin Development - get_option error

Tags: php, plugin-development

I am trying to put the option on selected with the built in function of wordpress called selected. I have tried to change the key from opt to different key names for every select field and it still didn't work.

At the moment i am stuck, see my code below:

```
$taxonomy_args = array(
    'public'    =>  true,
    '_builtin'  =>  false
);

$taxonomy_names = get_taxonomies($taxonomy_args);

$select_field = get_option('select_field');


echo "<form id='example_details' method='post' action''>";
    foreach( $taxonomy_names as $taxonomy_name ) {
        echo "<div class='div_fields'>";
        $taxonomy_name_lc = strtolower($taxonomy_name);
        echo "<label for='${taxonomy_name_lc}_select_field'>${taxonomy_name}</label>";
            echo "<select class='example_form_select' name='details_select_field[opt]' id='${taxonomy_name_lc}_select_field'>";
                echo "<option></option>";
                $terms = get_terms( array( 
                    'hide_empty'    => false,
                    'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy_name
                ) );
                
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    echo "<option id='" . $term->name . "' value='" . $term->name . "' " . selected(isset($select_field['opt']), $term->name) . ">" . $term->name . "</option>";
                }


            echo "</select>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    wp_nonce_field( $this->plugin, 'details_nonce' );
echo "</form>";
```

I did a var_dump on the $select_field variable but that one returns a boolean of false.

Comment: From your code it seem the option field name is `details_select_field[opt]` why you are trying to fetch `select_field` ?

Comment: Inside the wordpress codex selected(), i did get it from the examples. Do you know a solution to add the atribute selected? Because even when i don’t fetch it’s still not getting selected. But the boolean is returning true now.

Comment: `$select_field = get_option();` get me the var_dump of this. Then I can provide you working code.

Comment: I need to add an argument inside the function. I am trying to use the get_option function inside my custom metabox but i am now reading that i have to use get_post_meta? Hopefully you can make my wiser.

Comment: $all_options = wp_load_alloptions();
var_dump($all_options);  I doubt your option is being saved. I need to check

Comment: Also mention where are you trying to add the select field? Inside a metabox or admin page?

Comment: Inside a metabox. At a custom post type page> Add nee. And wp_load_alloptions is giving a lot of data.

Comment: then it's a meta. not option. try dumping `get_post_meta( get_the_ID());`

Comment: and add the result to the question.

Comment: So i was right about my thoughts. And i’am verry thankfull that you helped me sir.